# Win 10 : what registry keys entries are needed to reg my app for tel protocol

Tags: windows

About tel protocol handler : My app works fine except under window 10. What extra registry keys entries are needed under window 10 to registry app for tel protocol (so my app becomes default for tel protocol) ? My app doesn't have CLSID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a bunch of keys which are needed for tel protocol on net. But the most important for win 10 is [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications] MyApp="Software\MyApp\Capabilities". Of course under Capabilities you have to have tel protocol.